# FILL_PARENT and MATCH_PARENT

Tags: android, android-layout, backwards-compatibility

Right now I am using MATCH_PARENT all throughout my app.
I've decided to make the app available to Android 2.1 users but the MATCH_PARENT is not introduced till Android 2.2

How should I go about doing this if I want my app to use MATCH_PARENT when the Android version is 2.2 and above but use FILL_PARENT if it's 2.1 (or lower if I decide to open it to them later on)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`FILL_PARENT` and `MATCH_PARENT` are same thing, if the version the user is having is 2.2 or higher `FILL_PARENT` would be replaced by `MATCH_PARENT` automatically. So it's better to use `FILL_PARENT`, to support backward compatibility.
There was a blog on Android dev site about this, I hope you can find it, if you want to have more details on this.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it gets replaced automatically. I thought if it's depricated you should avoid it at all costs. Thanks!

Comment: @dokgu What makes you think that _deprecated_ means that one has to _avoid it at all costs_? If that were the case, there would be no migration path.

Answer (score 2):

Well they do the exact same thing, they just changed the syntax for 2.2+. I'd say just use FILL_PARENT always so that'll it always work if you plan on supporting 2.1 or lower.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `fill_parent` anymore even if you are supporting Android 2.1 or below. You may know that the Java compiler will convert constants like `FILL_PARENT` or `MATCH_PARENT` to their respective values statically in the class files. This also happens on layout XML files.

If you don't believe this, just try it on your emulator (you should declare `android:minSdkVersion="4"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`).